# AS3 play sounds in an array in a sequence

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

This is being programmed in Flash CS5.5:

I want to push a button, and play through the entire array one sound at a time.  When the first sound stops, the second begins, etc. all the way until the last sound plays.  When the last sound finishes, all sound should stop, and if you push the play button again, it should start over at the beginning, and play through all sounds again.

Currently, to advance to the next sound, you have to push the button again.  I'm thinking the SOUND_COMPLETE needs to be used... I'm just not sure how, hence the empty function.  I only want to have to push play one time to hear the entire array in a sequence.  Any ideas?

```
var count;
var songList:Array = new Array("test1.mp3","test2.mp3","test3.mp3");

count = songList.length;
myTI.text = count;
var currentSongId:Number = 0;

playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(currentSongId < songList.length)
{
var mySoundURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(songList[currentSongId]);        
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(mySoundURL);
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

mySoundChannel = mySound.play();
currentSongId++;
mySoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,handleSoundComplete)
}
if(currentSongId == songList.length)
{
    currentSongId = 0;
}
}

function handleSoundComplete(event:Event){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use functions to modulate what you do, this will make your code more readable.

```
private Array songList = new Array("test1.mp3", "test2.mp3");




public function onPlayBtnPressed(){
    currentSongIndex = 0;
    PlaySongFromIndex(currentSongIndex);
}


public function PlaySongFromIndex(songIndex:int){
    //do what ever here to simply play a song.
    var song:Sound = new Sound(songList[songIndex]).Play()
    //Addevent listener so you know when the song is complete
    song.addEventListener(Event.Complete, songFinished);
    currentSongIndex++;
}

public function songFinished(e:Event){
    //check if all the songs where played, if so resets the song index back to the start.
    if(currentSongIndex < listSong.Length){
        PlaySongFromIndex(currentSongIndex);
    } else {
        currentSongIndex=0;
    }
}
```

This wont compile its just to show an exemple, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.  I was able to figure it out by breaking it up per your suggestion.  Cheers!